# Transfer RPC metadata from one geotiff to another

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am performing an image processing task on one geotiff that produces another, however the metadata, including the RPCs, aren't propagated from the input to the output. Is there a way to copy the RPCs from the one image to the other, using GDAL or similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the gdal library in python:

```
from osgeo import gdal, gdalconst

# Open the files you want to transfer RPCs from and to
tif_with_RPCs = gdal.Open(tif_file_with_RPCs, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
tif_without_RPCs = gdal.Open(tif_file_without_RPCs,gdalconst.GA_Update)

# get the RPCs from the first file ...
rpcs = tif_with_RPCs.GetMetadata('RPC')

# ... write them to the second file
tif_without_RPCs.SetMetadata(rpcs ,'RPC')

# close the files
del(tif_with_RPCs)
del(tif_without_RPCs)
```

You can check this has worked with the command gdalinfo on the command line - the RPCs will be printed out if they are present

Comment: Any idea how to do that on a cloud storage directly, e.g. with /vsigs? I'm getting `Only read-only mode is supported for /vsicurl` on `tif_without_RPCs.SetMetadata(rpcs ,'RPC')`

Comment: I don't know, sorry! I've only ever had to this with GeoTIFFs stored locally.

Comment: Found a solution, a bit brutal because there's no append on vsicurl, so need to completely overwrite the file. I will post it as a second answer, not clear here in comments :)

Comment: implemented as a command line script: https://gist.github.com/maphew/29a73ee7a4517663cef5081c15799fc3

Answer (score 0):

To do that in Python on a cloud storage directly, with rasterio and vsicurl:

```
with rio.open(path_file_with_rpc, 'r') as src:
    rpcs = src.rpcs
with rio.open(path_file_without_rpc, 'r') as tile:
    metadata = tile.meta.copy()
    data = tile.read()
with rio.open(path_file_without_rpc), 'w', rpcs=rpcs, **metadata) as tile:
    tile.write(data)
```