# Converting 4 Band RGBA to 2 Band LA (Gray + Alpha) mode while keeping georeferenced data in GeoTiff

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, image

I created some GOES-16 images where the dark/night side of the visible image is transparent (alpha channel). I used satpy's DayNight Compositor to make the night side of the image transparent, while keeping the day time in gray scale. Unfortunately, using this method has converted the original L (gray) image into an RGBA image.

I tried using PIL to convert the image from RGBA mode to LA mode but it removes the georeferenced data in the GeoTiff.

```
img = Image.open(filename_of_RGBA).convert('LA')
img.save(new_filename)
```

How can I keep the georeferenced data while converting from RGBA to LA?

Comment: Here is some Python code to transfer metadata between geotiffs.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264644/transfer-rpc-metadata-from-one-geotiff-to-another

Comment: You can select bands with gdal_translate -b option, the real question is how to undo the pan sharpening, perhaps a GDAL_Calc on the bands to estimate the lightness that was used. Either option will retain your georeference.

Comment: @GRG for some reason when I tried the approach mentioned in the link, it didn't work for me.  I ended up finding a solution [link](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-How-to-read-all-metadata-from-GeoTIFF-file-td5377703.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy the georeferenced data from the RGBA image to the LA image by using a command line tool I found [here from David Strip-2](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-How-to-read-all-metadata-from-GeoTIFF-file-td5377703.html).

Given a GeoTIFF file named original.tif, and a modified file (modified.tif) without the GeoTIFF tags, but still the same size and region:

```
listgeo -no_norm original.tif > original.geo
geotifcp -g original.geo modified.tif modified_geotiff.tif
```